# What happens when RabbitMQ's Delivery Tag overflows?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

RabbitMQ uses a non-negative long (63-bit integer, because non-negative only) called a delivery tag to store how many messages have been sent over a channel. What happens if you send (2^63)+1 messages over a channel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to my back-of-napkin calculations, assuming a [maximum publish rate of 53,710 messages per second](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/25/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-2/), you would have to be publishing for a total of 7.06 x 10^13 years, which is four orders of magnitude greater than the age of the known universe.

Stated a different way, if we assume that somehow you could publish 3 messages per processor cycle, and that the Intel processor could process 7,000,000,000 messages per second, it would still take nearly 84 years.

Therefore, it is safe to conclude you will run into other issues first. But, if your RabbitMQ server manages to stay up and running that long, you deserve a prize.

But in all seriousness, if this were somehow to happen, I imagine it depends on how Erlang handles integers. [This post](http://www.programmersparadox.com/2008/02/05/erlang-integers/)  indicates that Erlang will run out of memory - I don't fully understand how they accomplish that, but maybe then the whole system blows up? Who knows.  In c#, the ints simply roll after [overflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Yes I know it would be unlikely to send this many messages. I was interested in what happens if you were to. While we can both imagine what happens, I was looking to see if anyone already knew or could point me to a reference.

Comment: Not "unlikely" - impossible, given your definition of the problem. But, I did attempt to theorize in the second part of my answer :) It may be that one could set up a test, whereby the integer value was deliberately set to (MaxValue-1) or sometthing, although I think it would be an academic exercise.

Comment: In java client, for example, you would have this fragment of `basicPublish` function `if (nextPublishSeqNo > 0) { unconfirmedSet.add(getNextPublishSeqNo()); nextPublishSeqNo++; }` with a negative long so it will never add it to the unconfirmedSet and never add 1 to get the next so I suppose you would get the same id and have related problems to it.